# How to convert Json string to xml in Golang?

Tags: json, xml, go

I'm trying to convert json string in to xml format using Golang. My whole object is to convert json in to map string interface and then convert interface in to xml file. (There is no predefined structs). Please help me to solve this issue?

```
var f interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an xml package that is equivalent to the json one under encoding. Just import it and then marshal the result of your `json.Unmarshal`

```
import "encoding/xml"
xml.Marshal(&f)
```

Comment: There was an issue when using this (xml: unsupported type: map[string]interface {})

Comment: @Himal ah yeah, it doesn't know how to marshal `map[string]interface{}` into valid xml, which isn't surprising considering how rigid xml is. You gotta use it with a more concrete type. Do you have use `map[string]interface{}`?